# Uso do SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Desenvolvi dois aplicativos para aprender Android e usei banco de dados MySQL. Até agora não encontrei necessidade de usar o SQLite e para ser sincero não entendi nem mesmo o porquê de sua existência.

Qual a utilidade do SQLite em um projeto?

Comment: SQLite é salvamento local, MySQL é remoto. Se você está utilizando MySQL para salvamento local, você está fazendo errado. É uma péssima abordagem.

Comment: Acho que me expressei errado, não utilizo o MySQL para salvamento local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral é usado para armazenar dados da aplicação no próprio dispositivo, como todo banco de dados.

Se não está fazendo isto deve retirar qualquer referência a ele na aplicação cliente que vai rodar no dispositivo.

Dê uma lida na [perguntas sobre o SQLite aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite?sort=votes&pageSize=50). Várias delas são sobre o uso no Android.

Só espero que esteja usando o MySQL no servidor e não no app.

Comment: Não use o MySQL no dispositivo. O SQLite é o disparado o banco de dados mais usado no mundo, deve ter bilhões de bases rodando nele. Eu uso até no servidor, mas não recomendo para iniciantes. Em cliente, desktop ou mobile a maioria das aplicações usa. Dê uma pesquisada na *tag* https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite?sort=votes&pageSize=50. Agora você pode votar em tudo no site também.

Comment: O SQLite tem suporte nativo no Android para armazenar dados no próprio dispositivo.